# Copy text to clipboard by clicking on SVG object

Tags: jquery, svg, clipboard

Is it possible to copy some text to clipboard by clicking on an element of SVG object using jQuery? I used Zero Clipboard for copying to clipboard by pressing simple button, but similar approach did not worked in this case - it could not bind flash to SVG object. Please advise - is there any way to do this?

My code report error SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified in zclip module.

```
<object data="vas.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="svgmap"></object>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(window).load(function () { 
var svgobject = document.getElementById('svgmap').contentDocument.getElementById('path3627');
jQuery(svgobject).zclip({
path:'ZeroClipboard.swf',
copy:'Some Text'});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `zclip` is confused because of the `svg` namespace of the element.

Bind to the `click` event of the element and invoke `clip.setText()` manually in the event handler.

Comment: Thank you, Aaron. But I have to glue the flash clip to the SVG object by using `clip.glue()` by providing object`s id. But SVG object is not accessible by id. Please advise.

Comment: Why do you have to "glue the flash clip"? Zero Clipboard works perfectly fine without attaching it to any DOM node. See http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/wiki/Instructions#Setting_Options for invoking it without "gluing"